# How to select one row from multiple which are with same column name in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with with columns name:

```
id
message
sender
chat_id
```

I want to get one row from number of rows with same chat_id ,during while loop fetch.

What Will be the MySQL Query

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Maybe an example will help

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one row, one of those columns needs to have **unique data** so you can add it to the WHERE clause

`SELECT id,message,sender,chat_id from information WHERE id=2` for example.

`SELECT id,message,sender,chat_id from information WHERE chat_id=5 AND sender='mark'`

OR during the while loop, match the column and grab whatever you want from it.
But again, it needs to be a **unique combination** of data otherwise it'll be overwritten by the previous.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
   if($row['sender'] == 'mark' && $row['chat_id'] == '5'){
   $thisIsMyRow = $row['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please could you explain more? What is it you're trying to achieve?

Say this is your query:

`SELECT id,message,sender,chat_id from messages WHERE chat_id=1`

You may have 200 rows that match that query. To return just one result, you can do a couple of things.

If you want the **latest** message, you can do this:

`SELECT id,message,sender,chat_id from messages WHERE chat_id=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

another example, **latest 5 messages**

`SELECT id,message,sender,chat_id from messages WHERE chat_id=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5`

In addition when you take it back into PHP, rather than going through the loop, you can JUST do this:

`$row = $result->fetch_assoc()`

As our query is only returning 1 row, you don't need to loop through. You can do this when your query returns multiple results - but it'd be better to optimise your query.

I can advise better if you are able to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$query = "SELECT id, message, sender,chat_id FROM messages WHERE Y = X AND Z = $K LIMIT 1";
}
```

replace the `WHERE` part with whatever column you want

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless - and executing a query inside a loop in this manner is poor practice.

Comment: @Strawberry why? It still will do the job of limitation, wouldn't it?